# Need translation for shipping label

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

I need the address below translated in to a specific address requirement.
zhang zhen
秋长镇白石村明泰路17号朝鲲产业园1号楼 CFF收货口
惠州市惠阳区
Shenzhen 广东省 516221

format needed:
Company
Address 1
Address 2
Address 3
Province
City
Postal Code

Comment: Just write your address like this: 秋长镇， 白石村，  明泰路17号，  朝鲲产业园 1号楼，  CFF收货口，  惠州市，  惠阳区，  深圳 ，  广东省，  516221 ， China

Comment: The word China is all you need to send your mail to China from any country. Once the mail arrived in China, the Chinese postal service will know where to send your mail by reading the address in Chinese. Basically Province and Postal Code are all they need

Answer (score 1):

秋长镇白石村明泰路17号（Address 1）
朝鲲产业园1号楼（Address 2）
CFF收货口（Address 3 ）
惠州市惠阳区（City&District）
广东省（Province）
516221（Postal Code）

Answer (score 1):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Company |  |
| Address 1 | CFF Shouhuo Kou, Chaokun Chanye Yuan 1 Hao Lou |
| Address 2 | Mingtai Lu 17 Hao |
| Address 3 | Baishi Cun, Qiuchang Zhen |
| City | Huiyang Qu, Huizhou Shi |
| Province | Guangdong |
| Postal Code | 516221 |